# How to upload thousands of images?

Tags: plugins, images, uploads, bulk

I have a website and 6000+ images in my computer. I am trying to upload 1000 pictures but it's not working, how can I upload all pictures in one and easy step for time saving?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a Plugin like [Add from Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/). This allows you to import all your images into the media library.

You just have to upload them to a folder on your server first.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the best method. I'll add a tip, being so many files and if it's possible: zip them all -> upload -> unzip on server (cPanel File Manager or similar). Uploading 1 file of 1GB takes **much less time** than uploading 1000 of 1MB files.

Comment: You are right @brasofilo, but one little thing there - I do not think that it makes a big difference if you upload big files (like 1MB) seperately - the big difference in time comes when you have a lot of small files, because you do not always have to make a new connection. Actually, for large files I prefer the seperated upload, as a lot can happen while I upload 1GB, and in this case I would have to start all over again.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, I've projected the "small file calculus" into a bigger ones case. The open/close ftp connection does not make a significant difference for bigger files. Thx for pointing this out :)